# Windows Update fails working on windows 7 with Error Code 8024200D

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

It may seem at first that we have many answers to this question but I tried them all but the update still fails.

Note: Windows 7 does not stuck in checking for updates. However, it downloads them but fails to install them : (No duplicates were found for this question).

Some of posts I've used to solve the issue:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-stuck-downloading-updates
Those all steps I have done:

> `1.  Stop the Windows Update related Services. 
>   net stop wuauserv  // Ok : mean operation succeeded
>   net stop bits`    // Ok

```
2. I deleted all files in:
 C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder and delete all the files and folders inside.
```

> ```
> 3. Restart the Windows Update related Services.
> net start wuauserv  // ok  
> net start bits      // ok
> ```

```
    4. I have tried **Windows Update Troubleshooter** (WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab) : It said that the problems were
    > solved !
```

> 5. Another try, I have installed the last update of **Windows Update Agent-7.6**

```
6. Last but not least: I tried to install failed updates manually but installation failed and sometimes cause system failure to start (need revert changes).

7. I tried a clean boot : disabled all non microsoft and startup services. Still updates failed with the same error.

8. Finally, I tried both WSUS offline updater 10.9 and Windows update MiniTool. Both of them failed.
```

Without forgetting doing a full Virus/Malware analysis and removal :D

[image]

After doing all of those steps and restarted my laptop many times the problem is not solved so any other methods to try are welcome.

Below part of my WindowsUpdate.log (Updated):

```
2017-01-21  21:15:20:871    1124    e2c AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {47F56A40-D8E6-4382-A523-1C96F796DCB9}]
2017-01-21  21:15:20:871    1124    e2c AU    # 97 updates detected
2017-01-21  21:15:20:884    1124    e2c AU  #########
2017-01-21  21:15:20:884    1124    e2c AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {47F56A40-D8E6-4382-A523-1C96F796DCB9}]
2017-01-21  21:15:20:884    1124    e2c AU  #############
2017-01-21  21:15:20:885    1124    e2c AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2017-01-21  21:15:20:901    1124    8d4 Report  REPORT EVENT: {EAE73EBD-E9E8-49B2-A8BF-AA599200389F}    2017-01-21 21:15:20:860-0000    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 97 updates.
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  #############
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  ## START ##  AU: Refresh featured updates info
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  #########
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  No featured updates available.
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  #########
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Refresh featured updates info
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  #############
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2017-01-22 18:30:12
2017-01-21  21:15:20:911    1124    e2c AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2017-01-21  21:15:20:953    1124    e2c AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2017-01-21  21:28:07:000    1124    cf4 AU  AU setting next sqm report timeout to 2017-01-22 21:28:07
2017-01-21  23:17:05:744    1124    174c    AU  Getting featured update notifications.  fIncludeDismissed = true
2017-01-21  23:17:05:745    1124    174c    AU  No featured updates available.
2017-01-21  23:17:05:846    1124    174c    AU  WARNING: Returning due to error from GetDownloadProgressUx, error = 0x8024000C
2017-01-21  23:17:05:846    1124    174c    AU  WARNING: GetInteractiveInstallProgress failed, error = 0x8024000C
```

Comment: @Run5k Hi, please note: Windows 7 does not stuck in checking for updates. However, it downloads them but fails to install them : (No duplicates were found for this question).

Comment: Download each update from the Windows catalog website and install them individually

Comment: @Ramhound Most of them fails !

Comment: Most isnt all...

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is this step is very time consuming ! And I would like to solve the update issue for future updates too. So I will not have to download them manually every time. Thanks.

Comment: Yes; But I am sure It's less trouble then doing a complete reinstall and downloading and installing hundreds of patches since SP1

Comment: Try removing after you perform an expert the following key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections** specifically **WinHttpSettings**

Comment: @Ramhound Are you suggesting to remove the key WinHttpSettings ? I think it will not help since the update are correctly downloaded but the problem is with the installation

Comment: @TheBeast - I am indeed suggesting you try that, and if it works, I will document an answer.  I have my suspicious beyond just my years of working with Windows that's my suggestion will work.  If you don't want to even attempt it I will just delete my comment.

Comment: If you want help with the other updates that fail to install, provide us those error codes, because `0x8024000C` is a proxy error

Comment: @Walmart - Don't be rude.

Comment: @Ramhound It taked some time but I tried it and it failed with the same error Code 8024200D. Do I need to undo that key in registry ?

Answer (score 0):

I had [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/1176907/630402).

Per this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1177234/630402):

> ...reset all the Windows Update, that way it will start anew. You can
>   use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc).  Run it As Administrator, use option 2 and 3,
>   and when finished restart the PC.
>
> If that does not help, I would suggest you trying to delete the
>   registry key
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌n\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired` (export it first to have a backup) and restart
>   the PC again.